# How to write Selenium Webdriver path address with python in Windows 10?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, filepath

I'm making a simple web crawler using Python with selenium. (Running on PyCharm Window 10)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(http://www.python.org)
```

I tried various formats for the file Path but all of them seem to return error.
What would be the correct format for the file Path? 
P.S. File address I copied off from File Explorer doesn't work either.

Comment: the best part is if you can directly copy paste the geckodriver.exe in C:\Python27 , then you need not to provide path in script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

There is no `Best Practice` to copy/access the driver executable in the Automation Script but on my `Windows 8 Pro` machine with `PyCharm IDE` through `Python 3.6.1`, I explicitly mention the absolute path of the driver executable so that I can work with different versions of different driver executable as well as different `Mozilla Firefox` versions as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I changed the paths more specific to my situation but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Actually it works with just the creating a driver variable with the path with the form you used.

Answer (score 0):

address should be within quotes as below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```