# Ironpython+Selenium can't launch the browser's driver

Tags: selenium, ironpython

I ran into a problem while working with VS2015 + Ironpython + Selenium:
the ironpython 2.7.7 has pip installed selenium,the scripts:

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

However,when the scrpts ran to `browser = webdriver.Ie()`, it throws a exception:

> Message: The executable IEDriverServer.exe needs to be available in
>   the path.

I try to put the IEDriverServer.exe to many paths including the ironpython's install path,the script's root path,the system32 folder,etc,but can't solve this problem.
PS:python2.7 with selenium can work properly,so did C# with selenium.but I just want try **ironpython** with selenium,that's the point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Selenium Webdriver path address with python in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094157/how-to-write-selenium-webdriver-path-address-with-python-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Put the *IEDriverServer.exe* any where within your system and mention the absolute path of the *IEDriverServer.exe* as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\IEDriverServer.exe')
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion,I've tried your method,but the problem was still exist